# Enable / disable submit button if input number higher than hidden input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I work on a form to allow users to bid on an auction. The form works well but I would like to disable the submit button if the bid is higher than the user balance.

Example: If the user balance is 20, the user cannot bid more than his balance.

I tried this code:

```
<form class="auction_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="906">
        
                    
        <input type="hidden" name="bid" value="906">    
            
            <div class="quantity buttons_added">
                                <input type="hidden" id="balance" value="5">
            
                <input type="number" id="bid_value" name="bid_value" data-auction-id="906" size="7" title="bid" class="input-text qty  bid text left">

            </div>  
        <button type="submit" class="bid_button button alt">Faire une offre</button>
                    
        <input type="hidden" name="place-bid" value="906">
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="906">
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1">
         
                </form>
                
<script>
$(document).on('input', '#bid_value', function(){
                    if ($(this).val() >= $('#balance').val() ) {
                        $('.bid_button').prop('disabled', true);
                    } else {
                        $('.bid_button').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
</script>
```

It seems to work well but in that case, the button stay enabled from 10...

I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: You missed that the values you are comparing are _strings_ …

Answer (score 1):

Because you're expecting `10 > 2` but in fact you're comparing `"10" > "2"` which returns false. Parse them as integers and then compare them.

```
var balance = parseInt($('#balance').val());
var bid = parseInt($(this).val());
if ( bid >= balance ) {
    //...
```